# trying to create a background with css with no luck

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website background similar to http://www.latlong.net/ but i'm not having any luck. Is this green and gray background one image or is that a green image at the top with a gray background?

I cannot find the css for the background to see what they have, it comes out all jumbled with alot of extra google maps css on it.

Can anyone see what they are doing to do the strip across the top and gray below?

Thanks!

Comment: `header {background-color: #D7E6B8;}` and `body {background-color: 
#EBEDE7;}`

Comment: how are they creating the divider?

Comment: Read the [css file](http://www.latlong.net/stylesheets/style.css).

Comment: ah thanks everyone for the answers, I was thinking this was an image. No wonder I didn't find it.

Comment: I'm new to css and learning so I expect images as backgrounds still... but I'll take the downvote if that is the cost of learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this out by using Chrome developer tools and inspecting the element:
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Looks like they are styling the header element using a background color and bottom border and shadow.

```
header {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color: #D7E6B8;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F8F8F8, #D7E6B8) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B5B09A;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: got it thanks! I'll upvote in 8 min.

Comment: first answer that helped me at time that I looked.

Answer (score 6):

Extracted from inspecting element with Chrome; You need:

```
body{
     background-color: rgb(235, 237, 231); /* This is #EBEDE7*/
}

header{
    background-color: rgb(215, 230, 184);    /* this is #D7E6B8*/
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shahverdy/NByX9/

#### How to find this?

Generally if you want to find out that how Html/Css of a webpage is working, the best way is to use some tools like *Chrome Developer Tools* instead of reading the Html/Css Files from source. There are some other tool in other browsers too.

In Chrome you need to right click on any element of the page and select *inspect element*.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an image but the background-color css attribute. You can do something like:

```
<header>My header</header>
```

with the CSS:

```
header { background-color: #D7E6B8 }
```

The body of your page can have css for the gray background:

```
body { background-color: #EBEDE7 }
```

Comment: For the divider add this to the header CSS:
....
border-bottom: 1px solid #B5B09A;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

Answer (score 1):

There is no background image in that, all are css background colors and shadows.just try with the following,

```
header {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F8F8F8, #D7E6B8) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B5B09A;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body {
    background-color: #EBEDE7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're referring to is the shadow.  It's not gray, but black with a high transparency.

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
```

This is on `<header>`, which also has a solid green `background-color` (actually `#D7E6B8`).

Answer (score 0):

Following classes are used in given page:

```
header {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F8F8F8, #D7E6B8) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B5B09A;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


body {
    background-color: #EBEDE7;
}
```